# Unit manila-api.service not found

Tags: openstack

I am trying to restart manila service as I have changed some configuration related to manila.

Manila is showing in dashboard and shares are also being created.
(even if it is with error status, which is I am trying to solve by modifying and it is mentioned here https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Manila/ManilaDevstack). so manila is up and running.

I have referred following link to restart manila service.

https://netapp.github.io/openstack-deploy-ops-guide/kilo/content/manila.configuration.html

command tried to restart is as following.

```
service openstack-manila-api restart
service manila-api restart
```

I am getting below by executing above.

Failed to restart manila-api.service: Unit manila-api.service not found.

Failed to restart openstack-manila-api.service: Unit openstack-manila-api.service not found.

What is wrong and why manila service is not being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Devstack the services would be called the following.

```
m-api
m-shr
m-sch
m-dat
```

e.g.

> systemctl restart m-api

or

> service m-api restart